# Modulus operator in c

Tags: c++, c, math, modulus

I need to check the divisibility of a number in c. How can I use the modulus operatpr in C to check if a number is divisible by another number? I tried doing this:

```
if (file_int % 3) {
    printf("Hoppity \n");
}
```

It didn't work, although file_int is equal to 9.

What did I do wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if (file_int % 3)` is the same as `if (file_int % 3 != 0)`, which is the opposite of what you want.

```
if (file_int % 3 == 0) {
    printf("Hoppity \n");
}
// or
if (!(file_int % 3)) {
    printf("Hoppity \n");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

It didn't work because the operation will return 0 which will be treated as false.

You actually need:

```
if(!(file_int % 3)) {
    printf("Hoppity \n");
}
```

Comment: could you please clarify that?

Comment: Indeed. If it's divisible, you should have a 0 remainder (equating to `false`) So, you can either `if (!(num % divisor))` or `if ((num % divisor) == 0)` (Basically inverting the false outcome to a true condition.)

Comment: `file_int % 3` is equal to `file_int % 3 != 0`, which is the condition for **indivisibility** by 3. The **divisibility** by 3 is `file_int % 3 == 0`, or equivalently `!(file_int % 3)`.

Comment: The modulo operator gives you the remainder after the division.  If a number is divisible by another, then that remainder is 0.  The if() conditional sees this as a false condition (anything non-zero is true) so the subsequent lines don't actually execute.

Comment: @AhmadGaffoor - In C when you cast an Integer to a Boolean value, 0 becomes false...anything else is true. Therefore if a number is evenly divisible, the modulus operator will return 0 which is false.

Comment: how can I use the modulus operator to check divisibility of two numbers?

Comment: Here, I used this to check for the 2num divisibility:

Comment: if (file_int % 5 == 0, file_int % 3 == 0) {
        printf("Hop \n");
    }

Comment: @AhmadGaffoor You need a logical AND there (`&&`), not a comma operator. `if (file_int % 5 == 0 && file_int % 3 == 0)`

Answer (score 1):

If the result of the modulus is 0, it is evenly divisible. It would appear you are looking for it to be not divisible by 3 to continue the loop, though your code snippet is not sufficient to confidently assume your intent.

Answer (score 1):

because if it is divisible by 3 `file_int % 3` will be equal to 0, and the if block won't execute.

Try

```
if(file_int % 3 == 0) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The mod operator returns the remainder resulting from the division... since 9 is divisible by three with no remainder, the return would be zero.

However, conditional statements evaluates to true if non-zero, false if zero.  You need to change it to `(file_int % 3 == 0)`.